# Create instance of class based on value of variable in python so I can use methods of class in future for each instance separately

Tags: python

I have to dynamically created class instance based on value on some variable

```
class A(object):
      def funct1(self):
       code....

      def func2(self):
        code..

var = 'string'
&var = A()
```

Now I want to created instace of Class A whose name is string.
How can I do with python or is there any aletranate to give unique name to each class instance at run time?

Comment: Just save your instances in a dictionary. Eg, `my_instances = {'some_name': A(), 'another_name': A()}`

Comment: How can I use methods of each instance when needed? I have to call few methods when time comes for instance of 'some_name'.

Comment: Like `my_instances['some_name'].funct1()`